# Do Chilis Ripen "off the vine"?

Tags: chili-peppers, ripe

In light of the question [Are chillies hotter when they're ripe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23604/6279), in particular – @ElendilTheTall's answer. I am wondering if chilies continue to ripen after picking?  If so, does capsaician continue to build up.

What is the 'peek of freshness/ripeness' for chilies? (assuming it is different for each type of pepper, but are there 'commonalities' to look for?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they will ripen off the vine (and gain capsaician in the process) because they are a climacteric fruit. They do this best in a paper bag, like most peppers. However, there is a limit to this because they will eventually wilt.

Comment: Thank you, could you expand on what a "climacteric" fruit is?

Comment: A climacteric fruit ripens by releasing ethylene gas and is capable of ripening off the plant they come from.